# Homestead link doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Trying to setup Homestead for laravel development. Did every step in laravel docs about homestead, but i cant get my project link running.

I added this line to hosts file

```
192.168.10.10 shop.dev
```

this is how my Homestead.yml file looks like:

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/users/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/users/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: e:/Projektai/Homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: shop.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Parduotuve/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

At first i had some problems running VM but I managed to get it working. However now this is not working at all.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of the `192.168.10.10`. I've found that instruction is not always correct.

Comment: should I change it in both files?

Comment: No, just the hosts file. The Homestead.yaml is fine.

Comment: And what link should I use to acces it now, shop.dev still? Because i tried that and it did not work

Comment: Yes, still shop.dev. What happened when you tried, with either IP in the hosts file?

Comment: Browser threw ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and thats it.

Comment: You may need to make sure that nginx is running inside of vagrant, and try `wget localhost` from the command line. On my system, it gives a `403 Forbidden`, but it tells me that nginx is at least running.

Comment: What is wget equivalent for windows? I used laragon before trying homestead and when i added shop.dev to hosts and when i run laragon shop.dev link sends me to laragon root folder. not sure how does this work

Comment: Do wget from inside of vagrant, so you can tell if it's a vagrant/nginx issue, or if it's something between windows and vagrant.

Comment: It says : Connecting to localhost .... failed: connection refused

Comment: Okay, so nginx isn't working inside of vagrant. You can try restarting nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`, and if it fails, check the logs. You can try over on superuser.stackexchange.com if it won't come up properly.

Comment: it did not fail nginx service wasnt installed at all or something. Now im more confused how should my Vagrant file look like, do I need to some more changes there or something else?

Comment: Oy, if it wasn't installed, then there's something else going on. That goes beyond what we can help you with here.

Comment: Hmmmm... What could cause that, any ideas? Should i try reinstalling everyting or something I have no clue with this problem..

Comment: You can try re-installing and see if that helps.